# How to change value by async.run with Petriflow?

Tags: application-server, petri-net

I have an action like this:

```
text: f.text;

async.run {
   change text value { return "My async text" }
}
```

But in Mongo, there is no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` action does not work in the `async.run` block because at the moment of execution it no longer has the required context to execute properly.

The proper way to do this is to use one of the [setData](https://petriflow.com/#/actions?id=setdata) methods. This is the preferred solution, as these methods trigger any `set` events that might be associated with the data variables you are trying to set.